# Have to point two dimensional graph(x,y) co ordinates networkx python

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am getting information from a spatial database the values are like line string(spatial) format and  i need to add this info to networkx graph later need to draw a graph in a matplot lib
I have written this code

```
cursor.execute("SELECT AsText(roadstring) FROM road1")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    a=row[0][12:-2]
    a=str(a)
    a=a.split(",")
    for i in a:
        i=i.split(" ")
        i[0]=float(i[0])
        i[1]=float(i[1])
        weig=abs(i[0]-i[1])
        G.add_node((i[0],i[1]))
```

I unable to get how to add two dimensional edges for roads (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) even i need to add weight to these edges for distance between them
Any suggestions??

The line string of every road  are like these `643715.202,2499149.0506 643752.61523545,2499089.86084203 643773.6038,2499056.6558 643773.73878609,2499056.44011079 643793.20162482,2499025.34111554 643813.55943268,2498992.81212045 643826.6563,2498971.8852`

I am getting this error I have matplotlib installed I tried by copying your code

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\python\gis\new.py", line
>   2, in 
>       from matplotlib import pyplot as plt   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 133, in
>   
>       from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 19, in
>   
>       from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 54, in
>   
>       import matplotlib.cbook as cbook   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 15, in
>   
>       import new   File "D:\python\gis\new.py", line 2, in 
>       from matplotlib import pyplot as plt   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 20, in
>   
>       from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive ImportError: cannot import name interactive

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example of the text you are trying to parse -- "AsText(roadstring)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want to accomplish, but here's how I interpret
it.

You have roads defined as coordinates along the road and you want to draw these
coordinates as nodes and the road between them as edges. You also want the edge
weight to be the distance between the two nodes.

This can quite easily be accomplished by saving the previous node and using the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance. This is
how I did it:

```python
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

G = nx.Graph()

row = '643715.202,2499149.0506 643752.61523545,2499089.86084203 ' +\
    '643773.6038,2499056.6558 643773.73878609,2499056.44011079 ' +\
    '643793.20162482,2499025.34111554 643813.55943268,2498992.81212045 ' +\
    '643826.6563,2498971.8852'

a=row.split(" ")
# Saving the previous node to be able to calculate the distance
prev_point = None
# Save the positions in a dictionary to be able to draw 
# the nodes at the correct positions
pos = {}
for i in a:
    cur_point = tuple([float(x) for x in i.split(',')])
    assert len(cur_point) == 2
    if prev_point is not None:
        # Calculate the distance between the nodes with the Pythagorean
        # theorem
        b = cur_point[1] - prev_point[1]
        c = cur_point[0] - prev_point[0]
        a = math.sqrt(b ** 2 + c ** 2)
        G.add_edge(cur_point, prev_point, weight=a)
    G.add_node(cur_point)
    pos[cur_point] = cur_point
    prev_point = cur_point
nx.draw(G, pos=pos)
plt.savefig('roads.png')
```

In this example I assume that a space separates the node positions and each
position's x and y coordinate is comma separated, but this can easily be changed. The above code will output something like this:

[image]

This will put the nodes at their "correct" positions, although it can cause some issues if there are big differences in road length. In the above example you can see that two nodes are more or less on top of each other. But that's a different question.

Comment: Just a comment: You can remove the `abs()` calls from `b` and `c` as they are later squared, anyway, so sign is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response  I also need to plot the graph in png format with a bounding box whoose max and min values are known

Comment: @kigurai Very true, removed them. @Rakesh I added the saving of an image as well. It sounds like you want the positions of the nodes to be the actual coordinates. `draw` can take a dictionary of positions and do that, [take a look here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw).

Comment: I need them to be at their real position can i do that through some other way

Comment: I need them to be at their real position can i do that through some other way What iam trying to draw is a set of roads on a geographical map

Comment: As I am plotting many roads i need a bounding box(start and end of image ) and many points are getting overlapped due to the huge scale used so need to shorten the scale also.

Comment: As I said in my answer, that's a different question. Try to formulate it as a good question and post it.